# Enlarge collapsed category button in wxPropertyGrid

Tags: wxwidgets

I have increased the font size of wxPropertyGrid.  Everything is zoomed satisfactorily except for the buttons that toggle collapsed categories, which remain small.

[image]

How do I increase the size of these buttons?

( wxWidgets 3.1, MSWindows )